Unrestricted Hartree Fock Procedure and Implementation
I am currently working on a homemade Hartree Fock program which works well for RHF calculations, but is currently failing for UHF; I was wondering if my general procedure for solving the Pople-Nesbet equations is correct. The procedure I am using:

Make initial guess for $P_{\alpha}$ and $P_{\beta}$ (I am just using Hcore).
Build $F_{\alpha}$ and $F_{\beta}$.
Orthogonalize $F_{\alpha}$ and $F_{\beta}$ (using $S^{-1/2}$).
Diagonalize $F'_{\alpha}$ and $F'_{\beta}$; the diagonal matrices correspond to the orbital energies $\varepsilon_{\alpha}$ and $\varepsilon_{\beta}$, and the unitary matrices correspond to the coefficient matrices $C'_{\alpha}$ and $C'_{\beta}$.
Unorthogonalize $C'_{\alpha}$ and $C'_{\beta}$ to get $C_{\alpha}$ and $C_{\beta}$.
Build new density matrices $P_{\alpha}$ and $P_{\beta}$ from the coefficient matrices and the number of alpha/beta electrons.
Return to step 2 and repeat until converged.

I am using the following expressions for $P_{\alpha}$ and $F_{\alpha}$ (K is the number of basis functions):
$$P_{\mu\nu}^{\alpha} = \sum_a^{N_{\alpha}} C_{\mu a}^{\alpha}C_{\nu a}^{\alpha}$$
$$F_{\mu\nu}^{\alpha} = H_{\mu\nu}^{core} + \sum_{\lambda\sigma}^K P_{\lambda\sigma}^T(\mu\nu|\sigma\lambda) - P_{\lambda\sigma}^{\beta}(\mu\lambda|\sigma\nu)$$
where $P^T = P^{\alpha} + P^{\beta}$. I am also computing the $\langle S^2\rangle$ value with the following formula (Szabo and Ostlund eqn. 2.271):
$$\langle S^2\rangle = \langle S^2\rangle_{exact} + N^{\beta} - \sum_{ij}^N |S_{ij}^{\alpha\beta}|^2$$
where $S_{ij}^{\alpha\beta} = \sum_{\mu\nu}^K C_{\mu i}^{\alpha}C_{\nu j}^{\beta} S_{\mu\nu}$
I am testing my program with the CH3 radical with the STO-3G basis set (one unpaired electron). It "converges" but the solution does not seem to be correct (many positive occupied orbital energies, the $\langle S^2\rangle$ value is -2000, and a Lowdin population analysis gives an overall charge of -7; for the population analysis, I am performing it with $P^T$ using the same general formula as for RHF calculations). Is there something wrong with this general procedure? As an aside, is there somewhere I can find more example calculations to compare my program to? It is difficult to find complete examples of UHF calculations compared to how available these examples are for RHF calculations. I can give more details if needed.
Thanks!
Edit: The code itself may be found here. Note that everything works fine for the restricted case and there seems to be no issues with the basis functions, integrals, or other low level routines. The issue seems to be only with the unrestricted case; the code for UHF is localized entirely within /main/hartree-fock.cpp and /libscf/scfuhf.cpp. There are also many sample inputs/outputs in /main/, as well as a failed CH3 run.
Also, I was able to make some adjustments. A wrong coefficient matrix was being used somewhere and in the expression for the UHF $\langle S^2\rangle$ I am summing over the alpha and beta electrons instead of just the total number. This helped somewhat (and UHF/RHF seem to match for even numbers of electrons) but the $\langle S^2\rangle$ is still wrong (7.513, should be 0.7652 per Szabo and Ostlund for CH3 radical). It is also strange as for CH3, I am getting only 4 negative alpha orbital energies (5 alpha electrons) and I am getting 5 negative beta orbital energies (only 4 beta electrons), but to the best of my knowledge I have not accidentally swapped any alpha/beta matrices.

I can't find obvious mistakes. I suggest to take a look at simpler systems (H atom, $\ce{H_2^+}$, closed shell cases) to narrow down the possible bugs.

Second @TAR86 Sounds like a bug, do the normal debugging things, check it gives the same answer as the restricted case when the number of alpha and beta electrons are the same

The NIST website is a good place to look for examples. Not sure about UHF though.

Thanks for everyone's help so far; I have tested my UHF program for H2 and it is not giving the same results as for RHF H2 (i.e. it is wrong). I will continue with debugging.

I was able to fix the total energy as well as the population analysis issue (just a code bug), but I noticed one possible issue in the UHF total spin: I was summing over N both times instead of Na and Nb for the respective alpha/beta orbitals. Now the spins are much more reasonable (~0 for Na=Nb and >Exact otherwise) but there is still an issue lurking somewhere as my UHF spin for CH3 is "better" than the literature value. It may be that I am using the wrong spin orbitals: my occ alpha have one positive orbital E while my virtual beta show one negative orbital E (maybe they are swapped?).

I do appreciate this question a lot and I think the original purpose, i.e. what are the steps to UHF, is a very good fit for the site. I believe the comments though summed that up already and this question is heading deeper into the territory of debugging code. It is possibly then no longer a good fit for our site, but it might be well suited for [mattermodeling.se] or [scicomp.se]. I propose that someone sums up the currently answerable part and you can build on that at the other platforms with more specialised questions.

@Martin-マーチン I was able to fix my issue; I will post an answer with the details.

Thanks for everyone's help; I was able to fix the issues. It seemed that I was actually using the wrong density matrices to build the Fock matrices (the beta density matrix in my original equation should have been an alpha density matrix and vice versa). Also, for $\langle S^2 \rangle$, I was summing over $N$ both times instead of only the occupied MOs (which would correspond to $N^\alpha$ for the first sum and $N^\beta$ for the second).
